# How to maintain window size when ContentControl changes

Tags: wpf, caliburn.micro

I have Page with a ContentControl.  The ContentControl is dynamically set to a UserControl which currently just contains a DataGrid.  When this happens, the Page is being resized in order to fit the contents of the DataGrid which happens to make the Page go off the screen.

If I change the Page width from Auto to a hardcoded value, then the Page width doesn't change when the ContentControl gets dynamically set.  This is the behavior I want.  However, this also means that when the user manually drags the window to become larger then the contents of the window won't expand any larger than the hardcoded width value that I set.

How can I cause the Page to maintain the same size when the ContentControl is set while still allowing the page to grow when the user increases the window size?

```
<Page x:Class="SageWpf.Views.ShellView"
      xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
      xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
      xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
      xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
      mc:Ignorable="d" Title="ShellView" MinHeight="450" MinWidth="800">

    <Grid Width="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=Page, AncestorLevel=1}, Path=Width}">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="200"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <Border Grid.Column="0" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="2" Width="193">
            <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" Width="188">
                <Button x:Name="ItemsScreen" FontSize="28" Height="65" Margin="1" Opacity="1">Items</Button>
                <Button x:Name="CheckoutScreen" FontSize="28" Height="65" Margin="1" Opacity="1">Checkout</Button>
            </StackPanel>
        </Border>

        <ContentControl x:Name="ActiveItem" Grid.IsSharedSizeScope="True" Grid.Column="1"></ContentControl>
    </Grid>
</Page>
```

As you can see I have a MinWidth of 800, and I would like the page to remain at this width when the CheckoutScreen button is clicked (which loads the ContentControl with a view that contains the DataGrid, as mentioned above).

Comment: Oh yeah, I accidently left in one of my attempts to fix this problem with the Grid Width binding... it didn't have any effect though.

Comment: Not sure if this is 100% right but as far as I remember there is a `Measure` pass and an `Arrange` pass for WPF controls. The page will do it's `Measure` first, then the grid will, but the grid does `Arrange` before the parent container and will see that `Page` has an infinite width and allow itself to grow. The page then arranges and realises it needs to be big to accommodate the grid. I'm sure I've got something like this working though without the need to resort to anything drastic...

Comment: I'll come back to you when I get some time!

Comment: Incidentally did you try binding `Width` and `Height` for the `Page` to the `Width/Height` of the `Window` that hosts them?

Comment: @Charleh Good question.  Honestly don't remember what all I tried right now but I'll give it a shot and let you know what happens.

Answer (score 0):

You could use something like this to let the window remain resizable by the user, but not by the control itself.

```xml
<Grid  ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
```